# how does hashing in java works?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashcode

I am trying to figure something out about hashing in java.
If i want to store some data in a hashmap for example, will it have some kind of underlying hashtable with the hashvalues? 
Or if someone could give a good and simple explanation of how hashing work, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: as i understand it hashing (in the context you're using it) produces a value that is garanteed to be equal for two objects that are equal and is unlikely to be equal for two objects which are not equal. This speeds up questions of .contains() and other methods that would call .equals(). A simple example would be if a class has members x and y then the hash code might be 71*(x+71*y), but an IDE will generate a good hash for you when you override equals

Comment: but where does the hashcode exactly go, after computing it?
Is it stored in some kind of underlying  hashtable ?

Comment: Do you understand [hashtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)? This is *not* meant to be a snarky comment; in all seriousness, if you really want to *grok* how hashing works, you need to understand the data structure. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is fantastic, as is the explanation in [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com).

Comment: I'd answer the question but wikipedia already has an excellent page about hash tables in the general data structure sense - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope i'll figure it out

Answer (score 10):

HashMap is basically implemented internally as an array of **Entry[]**. If you understand what is linkedList, this Entry type is nothing but a linkedlist implementation. This type actually stores both key and value.

To insert an element into the array, you need index. How do you calculate index? This is where hashing function(hashFunction) comes into picture. Here, you pass an integer to this hashfunction. Now to get this integer, java gives a call to **hashCode** method of the object which is being added as a key in the map. **This concept is called preHashing.**

Now once the index is known, you place the element on this index. This is basically called as **BUCKET** , so if element is inserted at Entry[0], you say that it falls under bucket 0.

Now assume that the hashFunction returns you same index  say 0, for another object that you wanted to insert as a key in the map. This is where **equals** method is called and if even equals returns true, it simple means that there is a **hashCollision**. So under this case, since Entry is a linkedlist implmentation, on this index itself, on the already available entry at this index, you add one more node(Entry) to this linkedlist. So bottomline, on hashColission, there are more than one elements at a perticular index through linkedlist.

The same case is applied when you are talking about getting a key from map. Based on index returned by hashFunction, if there is only one entry, that entry is returned otherwise on linkedlist of entries, equals method is called.

Hope this helps with the internals of how it works :)

Answer (score 5):

> If i want to store some data in a hashmap for example, will it have some kind of underlying hashtable with the hashvalues?

A `HashMap` *is* a form of hash table (and `HashTable` is another).  They work by using the `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` methods provided by the `HashMap`s key type.  Depending on  how you want you keys to behave, you can use the `hashCode` / `equals` methods implemented by `java.lang.Object` ... or you can override them.

> Or if someone could give a good and simple explanation of how hashing work, I would really appreciate it.

I suggest you read the Wikipedia page on [Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to understand how they work.  (FWIW, the `HashMap` and `HashTable` classes use "separate chaining with linked lists", and some other tweaks to optimize average performance.  As of Java 8, the optimizations include converting long hash chains into binary trees.)

A hash function works by turning an object (i.e. a "key") into an integer.  How it does this is up to the implementor.  But a common approach is to combine hashcodes of the object's fields something like this:

```
  hashcode = (..((field1.hashcode * prime) + field2.hashcode) * prime + ...)
```

where `prime` is a smallish prime number like `31`.  The key is that you get a good spread of hashcode values for different keys.  What you DON'T want is lots of keys all hashing to the same value.  That causes "collisions" and is bad for performance.

When you implement the `hashcode` and `equals` methods, you need to do it in a way that satisfies the following constraints for the hash table to work correctly:

```
 1. O1.equals(o2) => o1.hashcode() == o2.hashcode()
 2. o2.equals(o2) == o2.equals(o1)
 3. The hashcode of an object doesn't change while it is a key in a hash table.
```

It is also worth noting that the default `hashCode` and `equals` methods provided by `Object` are based on the target object's identity.

---

> "But where is the hash values stored then? It is not a part of the HashMap, so is there an array assosiated to the HashMap?"

The hash values are typically *not* stored.  Rather they are *calculated as required*.

In the case of the `HashMap` class, the hashcode for each key is actually cached in the entry's `Node.hash` field.  But that is a performance optimization ... to make hash chain searching faster, and to avoid recalculating hashes if / when the hash table is resized.  But if you want this level of understanding, you *really* need to *read the source code* rather than asking Questions.

Comment: But where is the hash values stored then? It is not a part of the HashMap, so is there an array assosiated to the HashMap?

Answer (score 4):

Hash values in Java are provided by objects through the implementation of [`public int hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) which is declared in `Object` class and it is implemented for all the basic data types. Once you implement that method in your custom data object then you don't need to worry about how these are used in miscellaneous data structures provided by Java.

A note: implementing that method requires also to have [`public boolean equals(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) implemented in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most fundamental contract in Java: [the `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).
The most important part of it here is that two objects which are considered `.equals()` should return the same `.hashCode()`.

The reverse is not true: objects not considered equal **may** return the same hash code. But it should be as rare an occurrence as possible. Consider the following `.hashCode()` implementation, which, while perfectly legal, is as broken an implementation as can exist:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() { return 42; } // legal!!
```

While this implementation obeys the contract, it is pretty much useless... Hence the importance of a good hash function to begin with.

Now: the [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) contract stipulates that a `Set` should not contain duplicate elements; however, the strategy of a `Set` implementation is left... Well, to the implementation. You will notice, if you look at the javadoc of `Map`, that its keys can be retrieved by a method called `.keySet()`. Therefore, `Map` and `Set` are very closely related in this regard.

If we take the case of a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) (and, ultimately, `HashMap`), it relies on `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`: when adding an item, it first calculates this item's hash code, and according to this hash code, attemps to insert the item into a given bucket. In contrast, a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (and `TreeMap`) relies on the *natural ordering* of elements (see [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)).

However, if an object is to be inserted *and* the hash code of this object would trigger its insertion into a non empty hash bucket (see the legal, but broken, `.hashCode()` implementation above), then `.equals()` is used to determine whether that object is really unique.

Note that, internally, a `HashSet` is a `HashMap`...

Comment: I think the requirement that `equals` defines an equivalence relation is even more fundamental, but the `hashCode` function is pretty important.  It may be helpful to say that `hashCode` should return different numbers for different objects to the extent that it can do so quickly, and without violating the requirement that matching values must have matching hashes.  Every hash collision that occurs will slow down hashed-collection lookup methods.  If a set with 50,000 items has a dozen collisions, slight slowdown.  If 20,000 items in the set all return the same hash, big slowdown.

Comment: @supercat yes, I know, I have illustrated it with an example of what _not_ to do ;)

Comment: Returning a static counter that's incremented on every call would be a lot more broken than returning 42. In some cases, if a type implements mutable-value equality, returning a constant (though perhaps one less "popular" than 42 or 8675309) may be sensible. If a type has a mutable `Name` field, and objects are considered `equal` if the `Name` matches, having `hashCode()` return `name.hasCode()` would work if no object's name changes while stored in a `HashSet`, but returning a constant `hashCode` would allow all objects to be found with current names, even if they had other names when stored.

Comment: @supercat I know all of that... And anyway, if you rely on `.hashCode()`/`.equals()` with mutable fields, you have a deeper problem to deal with ;) I don't have this problem since all instances I create are either immutable, or if they are not, leave this to `Object`....

Comment: I was merely commenting on your statement that returning a constant is "the most broken hashCode implementation"; it isn't, and there are times when it may be a reasonable thing to do (e.g. if one needs to store objects in a class which wraps a `hashSet<T>`, but a linear-searched collection type would have been better).  Actually, *quickly* returning a constant isn't even the most broken "legal" `hashCode` method; one which took a long time to come up with an answer which was the same for every instance would be more broken [BTW, I think one of .NET's types accidentally does just that].

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is a way to assign a unique code for any variable/object after applying any function/algorithm on its properties.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap stores key-value pair in Map.Entry static nested class implementation.
 HashMap works on hashing algorithm and uses hashCode() and equals() method in put and get methods.

When we call put method by passing key-value pair, HashMap uses Key hashCode() with hashing to find out
 the index to store the key-value pair. The Entry is stored in the LinkedList, so if there are already
 existing entry, it uses equals() method to check if the passed key already exists, if yes it overwrites
 the value else it creates a new entry and store this key-value Entry.

When we call get method by passing Key, again it uses the hashCode() to find the index
in the array and then use equals() method to find the correct Entry and return it’s value.
 Below image will explain these detail clearly.

The other important things to know about HashMap are capacity, load factor, threshold resizing.
 HashMap initial default capacity is 16 and load factor is 0.75. Threshold is capacity multiplied
 by load factor and whenever we try to add an entry, if map size is greater than threshold,
 HashMap rehashes the contents of map into a new array with a larger capacity.
 The capacity is always power of 2, so if you know that you need to store a large number of key-value pairs,
 for example in caching data from database, it’s good idea to initialize the HashMap with correct capacity
and load factor.